# Windows 7, Outlook 365, links default to chrome, I prefer Firefox

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-outlook

I am using Outlook 365 on Windows 7.  When I get an email with a link in it that the sender inserted, and when I click these links, the link request is opened up in Chrome.  I don't use Chrome very much, so I'd like these links to open in Firefox instead.  Is there a setting in Outlook where I can change which browser will open these clicked links?  I've had this problem on older versions on Outlook as well, but could never figure out how to do this.

Comment: Outlook launches your default browser.  If its launching Chrome that's like the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like Google Chrome is your default browser. To make Firefox your default browser, open Firefox, click the three-bar menu icon and select Options. In the Options dialog box, click **Advanced** and then select the **General** tab. Near the bottom of the page there will probably be a button saying "Make Firefox the default browser".

If there was no button, Firefox is already your default browser and you need a different approach. Open **Control Panel** and click on **Programs**. Under **Default Programs** click on **Set your default programs**. Locate Firefox in the list, click it and then click **Set this program as default**.